# saving bitmap doesnt work on dialogfragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, bitmap

When I copy past the **working** code from the fragment to the dialogfragment suddenly it doesn't work.

on regular fragment: save the bitmap on sd card.

on dialogfragment: doesn't save the bitmap on sd card.

dialog fragment:

```
    package com.example.smite.floater;

    import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.app.Dialog;
    import android.app.DialogFragment;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat;
    import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Environment;
    import android.text.Layout;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;

    /**
     * Created by smite on 09/08/2015.
     */
    public class DialogEditText extends DialogFragment {

        TextView textView;

        ImageView img;

        Bitmap bitmap;

        BitmapDrawable drawable;

        EditText editText;

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

            LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

            builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialogedittext, null));
            builder.setTitle("Pick a name");

            View creatorLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.creator, null);

            textView = (TextView)creatorLayout.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            img = (ImageView)creatorLayout.findViewById(R.id.img);
            editText =(EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.edittext);

            builder.setPositiveButton("save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    textView.buildDrawingCache();
                    Log.d("d", "buildDrawingCache");
                    img.setImageBitmap(textView.getDrawingCache());
                    Log.d("d", "buildDrawingCache2");
                    drawable = (BitmapDrawable) img.getDrawable();
                    bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
                    File sdCardDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                    File image = new File(sdCardDirectory, "edittext.png");
                    Log.d("d", "created image");

                    boolean success = false;

                    FileOutputStream outputStream;

                    try {
                        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(image);
                        Log.d("d", "created image");
 //line : 79            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream);
                        outputStream.flush();
                        outputStream.close();
                    }catch (FileNotFoundException ex1) {
                        ex1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    DialogEditText.this.getDialog().cancel();
                }
            });

        return builder.show();

    }
}
```

logcat error:

```
08-10 04:06:56.566  16710-16710/com.example.smite.floater E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.smite.floater, PID: 16710
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.smite.floater.DialogEditText$1.onClick(DialogEditText.java:79)
        at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

craetor xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/siganture_creator"
        android:hint="@string/signature..."
        android:imeOptions="actionDone|flagNoExtractUi"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/signature..."
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:textSize="50dp"
                />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/img"
                android:visibility="gone"
                />

    </LinearLayout>


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="save"
        android:id="@+id/save"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks for helping guys (:

Comment: can you put `R.layout.creator` xml content also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a bitmap from a view, view should be drawn. In your case you are inflating `R.layout.creato` layout, getting an instance of it and you have not used `setView()` or `addView()` method to draw that layout. In other word you have created just a different instance of `creator` layout and it is not displayed yet thats why bitmap is null.

Try using getActivity() method to get instead of `creatorLayout` variable. It should help you. it will find view in activity scope.

Have a look at following edited code:

***Edited***

@Override 
            public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

            builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialogedittext, null));
            builder.setTitle("Pick a name");

            textView = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView);
            img = (ImageView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.img);
            editText =(EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.edittext);

            builder.setPositiveButton("save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override 
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    textView.buildDrawingCache();
                    Log.d("d", "buildDrawingCache");
                    img.setImageBitmap(textView.getDrawingCache());
                    Log.d("d", "buildDrawingCache2");
                    drawable = (BitmapDrawable) img.getDrawable();
                    bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
                    File sdCardDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                    File image = new File(sdCardDirectory, "edittext.png");
                    Log.d("d", "created image");

                    boolean success = false;

                    FileOutputStream outputStream;

                    try { 
                        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(image);
                        Log.d("d", "created image");
 //line : 79            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream); 
                        outputStream.flush();
                        outputStream.close();
                    }catch (FileNotFoundException ex1) {
                        ex1.printStackTrace();
                    } 
                    catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } 

                } 
            }); 
            builder.setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override 
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    DialogEditText.this.getDialog().cancel();
                } 
            }); 

        return builder.show();

    }
```

Comment: I dont understand what you meen when you say "Try setting drawable in this "ImageView" your problem should be solved."? how to set drawable?

Comment: thanks for helping but it doesn't work and on creator java file it is work without changing

Comment: check you must have added drawable to `img` ImageView instead there also has been NullPointerException. Because no drawable is assigned there how is it possible to get Drawble from it.

Comment: There is a drawable. It takes the textview as a drawable by build drawing catche and set in the imageview  imageBitmap

Comment: Sorry its my bad i overlooked that line of code. So the problem is you are inflating creator.xml layout and getting instance of all views but you r not setting that layout to a view. Hance that layout is not drawn so textview can not generate bitmap that is why nullpointerexception is being thrown.

Comment: I didnt get it . It id View View creatorLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.creator, null);     please you can show me my mistake.

Comment: First let me clear one thing you want to get bitmap of textview where this textview resides, on activity? or the dialog you are creating?

Comment: From where the textView resides from the creator fragment.

Comment: Means textview is in the fragment and from that fragment you are showing dialog.